# Does a ultimate edition disc work even after I played with a standard edition disc?

Tags: xbox-360, star-wars-the-force-unleashed

I have force unleashed standard edition on my xbox 360 (disc), and I want to buy the ultimate sith edition of the game (it include dlc's and stuff). Would the game work if I put the ultimate sith edition in even though I have the standard edition installed?